# apply function to each column using different parameters

Tags: r

I want to apply the BoxCox function to each column of a time series matrix:

```
lapply(ts_data, function(x,lambda) {BoxCox(x,lambda)}, lambda = 0.4)
```

The problem is, that I don't want to fix lambda for each column to a fixed global parameter. Instead I have a vector `vec_lambda` containing different lambdas, for each column of `ts_data` some different `vec_lambda` was precalculated.

Any idea how to use `lapply` or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a `data.frame`, we can use `Map`

```
Map(BoxCox, ts_data, lambda = v1)
```

where 'v1' is the `vector` of `lambda` values which is equal to the number of columns of the 'ts_data'

---

If it is a `matrix`, then loop through the sequence of columns

```
lapply(seq_len(ncol(ts_data)), function(i) BoxCox(ts_data[,i], lambda = v1[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you could use `mapply`, mapply has methods for `data.frame` and `list`

```
#a bit modified from mapply help page example
mapply(function(x, y) sqrt(x) + y,  #BoxCox
   data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),y=c(4,5,6),z=c(7,8,9)),  #ts_data
   c(A = 10, B = 0, C = -10)) .  #lambda
```